# How to use it as a subject

Tags: usage

> It was in 2006 **that** we first flew to the United States.

I think the above sentence is correct. But my book says **when** should be used in place of **that**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are right: "that" is fine. "When" is also correct. In examples like yours, it's a free choice between a _wh_ relative and a _that_ relative. Incidentally, why do you think "that" is a subject?

Comment: Please elaborate. Which book are you talking about? What does it say? Does it explicitly say that using "that" would be wrong? Or does it simply use a different version of the sentence, and you are wondering if your rewrite is acceptable?

Comment: Don’t put a number in your title - write a more descriptive title. There is advice on writing a good title in this thread on meta: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-can-i-write-a-better-title-for-my-ell-question

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker I see absolutely no problem with both of these words being used. However, I think I would naturally use 'when' instead of 'that', but I am unsure why.

To me, when you say 'it was in 2006 that we first flew to the United States', it makes it sound like you are about to say something bad about the experience or reel out a long story. It almost sounds more poetic/formal.

Answer (score 0):

> *It was in 2006* [*that we first flew to the United States*].

You are right: "that" is fine. "When" is also correct. In examples like yours, it's a free choice between a *wh* relative and a *that* relative.

Note, though, that "that" is simply a subordinator. The relative pronoun is missing, but represented by the '____' notation, called gap, which indicates the covert presence of the relative pronoun functioning as an adjunct of time, which has "2006" as antecedent:

*It was in 2006* [*that we first flew to the United States ____*].